# SpatioTemporal Package error: "Length of 'LUR.in' does not match number of temporal trends."

Tags: r

The full dataset and code I am asking about here can be found at: https://github.com/claytonglasser/siuslaw-basin-precipitation

I am following the [Comprehensive Tutorial for the Spatio-Temporal R-package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/SpatioTemporal/vignettes/ST_tutorial.pdf) using my own data. I am able to track with all of the steps until I get to the "3 createSTmodel(): Specifying the Spatio-Temporal model" section at which point I encounter the following error, which I am having trouble interpreting.

My code is as follows:

```
LUR <- list(~ELEVATION)
cov.beta <- list(covf="exp", nugget=FALSE)
cov.nu <- list(covf="exp", nugget=~ELEVATION, random.effect=FALSE)

locations <- list(coords=c("LONGITUDE","LATITUDE"), long.lat=c("LONGITUDE","LATITUDE"))

siuslaw.ST.model <- createSTmodel(siuslaw.ST, LUR=LUR, 
                                  ST=NULL,
                              cov.beta=cov.beta, cov.nu=cov.nu,
                              locations=locations)
```

When creating the siuslaw.ST.model variable, this error is returned:

```
Error in processLUR(STmodel, LUR) : 
  Length of 'LUR.in' does not match number of temporal trends.
```

I don't know how to approach fixing this problem because I'm not sure how to inspect/evaluate the components 'LUR.in' and 'temporal trends'.

**Question:** My assumption is that there there is one temporal trend per Location, so therefore 10 in this case. However, I also use the following code to command the Siuslaw.ST object to use 2 temporal basis functions. Is this the "temporal trends" being referred to?

```
siuslaw.ST <- updateTrend(siuslaw.ST, n.basis=2)
```

**Question:** I don't understand how the LUR argument works, what kind of object it expects to take as input, or how critical of a role it has.

LUR.in is defined as: *A vector or list indicating which geographic covariates to use.*

In the tutorial, multiple covariates are listed, prepended with ~'s like they are formulas. I only have the one LUR item, ELEVATION, from the siuslaw.ST$covars object:

```
> siuslaw.ST$covars
# A tibble: 10 x 4
   ID          LATITUDE LONGITUDE ELEVATION
   <chr>          <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>
 1 US1ORLA0076     44.0     -124.      20.7
 2 US1ORLA0003     44.0     -124.      20.4
 3 US1ORLA0031     44.0     -124.      25.6
 4 US1ORLA0091     44.1     -124.      64  
 5 USC00352973     44.0     -124.      22.9
 6 USC00352972     44.0     -124.       3.7
 7 USC00353995     43.9     -124.      35.1
 8 US1ORLA0171     43.8     -123.     180. 
 9 USC00355204     44.0     -124.       5.2
10 US1ORLA0132     44.1     -124.      74.4
```

Notice there are 10 observations of ELEVATION. I think the LUR argument knows to look in siuslaw.ST$covars for the input, where I think it would find a single vector of 10 observations.

So in summary, why doesn't "Length of 'LUR.in' does not match number of temporal trends." and what do I need to inspect/change to in order to make them match?

I know this question is a bit of a hydra. Please let me know anything I can clarify and I am happy to do so.

Answer (score 0):

I was able solve this through experimentation. The discrepancy between the LUR.in and the number of temporal trends was due to LUR argument missing the rest of the geographic coordinates. Ultimately, I was able to succeed at creating the model by modifying the input for the LUR argument like so:

```
LUR <- list(~ELEVATION, ~LATITUDE, ~LONGITUDE)
```

The tutorial chooses to list an arbitrary subset of 3 of the geographic covariates in LUR, and still works. I can't say I totally understand why all three of these formulas needed to be specified, as opposed to just ELEVATION. If anyone with more knowledge can shed some light on this, that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible you did not specify the "locations" list with both x,y and long,lat? If that does not happen, then it could interpret the long/lat as spatial covariates, which means you would then need to specify it in the "LUR" input. This would explain why adding them as covariates remedied your situation. However, I am surprised not having both x,y and long,lat specified did not throw an error.